# In spark streaming, is there a way to dynamically add new computations to existing stream?

Tags: apache-spark

I am new to spark and trying to figure things out. We have a usecase where different users want to process the data differently in real-time and these users come and go. As I understand, I can create a stream for the underlying data and go into a foreachRDD to run my computations. But this assumes that I know all the computations I need to do a'priori.

Is it possible to add additional computations by going into the foreachRDD in a separate thread when a new User requires a new computation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, is not possible at the moment. The code inside foreachRDD is serialized and sent to the workers. foreachRDD is just one of the steps inside a DAG (like an execution plan), so it will be very difficult to chang at runtime.
The way to allow something similar is the following:
1) add kafka in front of your stream, in order to have a buffer before spark streaming
2) when you want change code, you have to stop the spark streaming context, change the code, recompile the job and resubmit the job.

Kafka will buffer data during the stop time of spark, so you will not lose data.

Comment: This is incorrect and never was correct. `foreachRDD` is executed on the driver. Please reference: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#output-operations-on-dstreams